# Web worker onerror

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Do web workers provide some method of finding out what data was posted to them if they fail?

So if I have the following code is there anyway to find out the contents of someData in the `onerror` handler if it fails or would I just have to keep track of it?

```
var someData = {...};
myWorker.postMessage(someData);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web workers do not provide any dedicated method *of finding out what data was posted to them if they fail*.

But that's quite easy to do manually, you can either handle `onerror` from outside, or do the deeper inspection in the `onmessage` handler from inside of the worker (where you have access to the message event):

```
// this one-liner was wrapped in order to improve legibility
var w = new Worker( URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([ " self.onmessage = function (evt) {\
        console.log(evt.data);\
        throw new Error('SOMETHING.WENT.WRONG.'); } "
    ])
));
w.onerror = function (err) {
    console.log('worker is suffering!', err)
};
w.postMessage(123);
```